# how to do ? once we sign in in the flutter application using google fire base then we do not have to sign in again whene we again open the app

Tags: firebase, flutter

once we sign-in in the flutter application using google firebase then we do not have to sign in again when we again open the app 
my sign in code

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
  try {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    final FirebaseUser user =(await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    print("signed in " + user.displayName);
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            return HomePage();
          }));

    // print("signed in " + user.displayName);
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question and description are a bit confusing. Is your objective to have the user permanently logged in after the first time they logs in? Meaning that if they close the app and start it again the user would still be logged in?

Comment: once user sign up first time if they close the app and again came to the app they do not have to sign up again they will directly navigate to the home page

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this is to use firebase functions to generate a token when you login the user and then save that token with SharedPreferences. Next time the user opens the app you retrieve the token and use it to automatically authenticate with Firebase. The Firebase function below will generate a token for the user you already have logged in:

```
exports.generateTokenCall = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  var token;
  token = admin.auth().createCustomToken(context.auth.uid)
    .then((customToken) => {
      return {
        token: customToken
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
      return { error };
    });
  return token;
});
```

An here's an example of the Flutter methods that I am using to login and auto login:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
CloudFunctions _cloudFunctions = CloudFunctions(region: 'europe-west1');
Firestore _instance = Firestore.instance;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;
User user;

Future<FirebaseUser> login(String email, String password) async {
  return await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password
  ).then((user) async {
    _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _sharedPreferences.setString('uid', user.uid);
    _sharedPreferences.setString('lastLoginDateTime', DateTime.now().toString());
    firebaseUser = user;
    loadUser(user.uid);
    return user;
  }).catchError((error) {
    print('failed signInWithEmailAndPassword');
    print(error.toString());
    return false;
  });
}

void attemptAutoLogin() async {
  _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String token = _sharedPreferences.get('token');
  String uid = _sharedPreferences.get('uid');

  if(token != null && uid != null){
    await generateAndSaveTokenCall();
    _auth.signInWithCustomToken(token: _sharedPreferences.get('token')).then((fbUser){
      if(fbUser is FirebaseUser && fbUser.uid != null){
        firebaseUser = fbUser;
        _sharedPreferences.setString('lastLoginDateTime', DateTime.now().toString());
        _instance.collection('users').document(firebaseUser.uid).get().then((snapshot) async {
          loadUser(firebaseUser.uid);
        });
        tokenUpdateTimer();
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }).catchError((error){
      setLoading(false);
    });
  } else {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}

Future generateAndSaveTokenCall() async {
  Map response = await _cloudFunctions.call(functionName: 'generateTokenCall').timeout(Duration(seconds: 30));
  print('generateAndSaveTokenCall');
  print(response);
  if(response['error'] == null && response['token'] != null){

    _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _sharedPreferences.setString('token', response['token']);
    _sharedPreferences.setString('lastLoginDateTime', DateTime.now().toString());
  }else{
    print('Error fetching token: ${response['error']}');
  }
}
```

*Please note that this is my own code that I'm sharing and will need adaptation for your own purposes.*

Comment: If i use Firebase googleSign then this method will work or not

Comment: If I use googleSignIn authentication then before that method we have to call this attemptautologin()  method

Comment: I haven't tested it with google sign in, myself. Theoretically you are signed in to Firebase, it should work. Give it a try.

Comment: Future < FirebaseUser > signUp(email, password) async { 
    final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)).user; 
    user.sendEmailVerification();
    return user;
  }

Comment: The above code is for user verification is it correct because it is not sending the verification email to the user

Comment: It's just a standard username and password account creation on Firebase Auth. It's not doing any email validation. That's a setting you can set yourself.